# MvcMailer, Find the file name of the email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcmailer

I'm using MvcMailer to save emails to a specified directory locally in my asp.net mvc web application. However I would like to save the file name (e.g. 90b871cd-038f-400a-b4d7-01f87e8c3c26.eml) of the email in the database which will later be accessed using another exe to send emails from the pick up folder.

Could you please advise me on how to retrieve the file name from the mail object?

```
var mail = Mailer.Example_Mail()
mail.To.Add("some@somedomain.com");
mail.Send();

<smtp from="some@somedomain.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <network host="localhost" />
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp\" />
</smtp>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be helpful for someone who will be seeking the answer for the same question. I managed to overcome the issue writing a reflection of System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.Send() as follows.

```
    public static string SaveToTemp(this MailMessage Message)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".eml";

        string fileNameWithPath = Path.Combine(smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation, fileName);

        Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        Type _mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

        using (FileStream _fileStream = new FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
            ConstructorInfo _mailWriterContructor =
                _mailWriterType.GetConstructor(
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null,
                    new Type[] { typeof(Stream) }, 
                    null);

            // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
            object _mailWriter = _mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { _fileStream });

            // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
            MethodInfo _sendMethod =
                typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod(
                    "Send",
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call method passing in MailWriter
            _sendMethod.Invoke(
                Message,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new object[] { _mailWriter,true, true },
                null);

            // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
            MethodInfo _closeMethod =
                _mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod(
                    "Close",
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            // Call close method
            _closeMethod.Invoke(
                _mailWriter,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new object[] { },
                null);
        }
        return fileNameWithPath;
    }
```

Caller:

```
var mail = Mailer.Example_Mail()
mail.To.Add("some@somedomain.com");
var fileName = mail.SaveToTemp(); // Instead of mail.Send();
```